# Pm2 error while deploying Strapi App on DigitalOcean

Tags: deployment, environment-variables, config, digital-ocean, strapi

I've been following the official docs for deploying a Strapi app onto Digital ocean, but I'm having trouble setting up pm2.
It starts the app for a second, and then shows

```
status: errored
```

there's no script.js to run the app, but when I cd to /home/myusername/appname/backend and run npm start, it works just fine, which leads me to believe that I have the ENV variables set correctly

Here's the config file

```
module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      name: 'strapi',
      cwd: '/home/your-name/project/backend',
      script: 'npm',
      args: 'start',
      env: {
        NODE_ENV: 'production',
        DATABASE_HOST: 'localhost', // database endpoint
        DATABASE_PORT: '5432',
        DATABASE_NAME: 'strapi', // DB name
        DATABASE_USERNAME: 'your-name', // your username for psql
        DATABASE_PASSWORD: 'password', // your password for psql
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

Then I run pm2 logs, I see

```
2020-07-13T01:58:49: PM2 log: App [strapi:0] online
PM2        | 2020-07-13T01:58:49: PM2 error: Error: spawn node ENOENT
PM2        |     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:19)
PM2        |     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
PM2        |     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. First replace:

```
    NODE_ENV: 'production',
    DATABASE_HOST: '127.0.0.1', // database endpoint
    DATABASE_PORT: '5432',
    DATABASE_NAME: 'THE DB NAME EX.SAMMY'
    DATABASE_USERNAME: 'THE DB USERNAME EX.SAMMY'
    DATABASE_PASSWORD: 'THE DB PASSWORD'
```

2. pm2 del 0 (check strapi app with pm2 start)
3. pm2 start ecosystem.config.js

Comment: Thank you. Deleting the app did it.

Comment: Is a database_host required? I'm getting this error but not using one.

Comment: SeanMC, don't you use a database in your project?

Answer (score 8):

for me it was because `cwd` was already relative and didn't like how my path was structured. I tried `~/my-app` as well as `/home/me/my-app` and both were wrong. It eventually just wanted `my-app`.

Comment: That was my exact problem. Not the formatting, but just I had an invalid path for my `cwd`. It was a simple mistake but once I corrected it - I was online with no error. Thanks!

Comment: Same problem deploying to EC2. Solved with this, thanks!